# sublime text 2, i can not use double click to select a word

Tags: sublime-text-2

Characters that are considered to separate words:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Triple-clicking I can select the line, but double-clicking, I cannot select the word, why?

I just can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to select a word.

Comment: Have the same problem in Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 1):

Add the setting to your User Preferences and pick and choose which characters you want to be treated as part of a word.

If you don't want any to be treated differently, add a blank string.

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?" // Remove '#'

"word_separators": "" // All treated as words.
```